# How to work cross-domain with signalr?

Tags: cross-domain, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

I want to make a demo with cross domain where the client is in a different project than the server. I know this is possible cause i found a lot of this on stackoverflow. Still with all the information i read about i didn't succeed to do this.
The demo i want to do this with:
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20

I'm doing this in my client to connect with my server :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var connection = $.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:33691/signalr';
    connection.hub.start().done(function () {
          alert('Now connected');
    }).fail(function () {
        alert("fail!");
    });
</script>
```

I'm using signalR 2.0 and i get this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of undefined
```

and the localhost:33691 is my server.

And in my server i have this in startup.cs :

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Branch the pipeline here for requests that start with "/signalr"
            app.Map("/signalr", map =>
            {
                map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
                {
                   EnableJSONP = true
                };
               map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
            });
        }
```

I also added this in my web.config on my server :

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

So my question is what am i doing wrong ? or what did i forget or does someone have a clear demo of this online somewhere ?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
Problem solved by myself

Comment: This is also my question. Would you be willing to share your solution?

Comment: Could you post the solution on how you solved this.